# Haskell - iso on newtype

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, lenses

If I have a `newtype`

```
newtype Foo = Foo Int
```

is there an automatic way to get an `Iso' Foo Int`?

I saw I could use `makeLenses ''Foo`, but I don't know what is the name of the generated iso.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`coerced :: (Coercible s a, Coercible t b) => Iso s t a b`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.19/docs/Control-Lens-Iso.html#v:coerced)

Answer (score 1):

If you name the accessor: `newtype Foo = Foo {_unFoo :: Int}` and then do makeLenses ''Foo, it will generate the Iso you want under the name "unFoo"

Note that the accessor must start with an underscore for it to generate the Iso.